# How to download my program from the nitrous.io's server?

Tags: nitrousio

Now, i wrote some program source.but i want to store them into my computer. How to download my program into my computer from the nitrous.io's server?Who can help me, i need your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the IDE. Go to the file you want in the file system view on the left and right click and select "download file".

Comment: thanks for your help.But my computer can't download the file which i want to.

Answer (score 6):

You can upload projects by any of the following options:

1. Upload a zip file, and extract it using 'unzip' command in the console.
2. Utilize the Mac App to Sync your files ( http://www.nitrous.io/mac , an update for Mavericks and also a Windows app is coming soon!)
3. Upload your project to Github, and pull the project from there. ( http://help.nitrous.io/github-add-key/ )
4. Upload the content via SCP. To do this, you will need to add an SSH Key to your account ( http://help.nitrous.io/ssh-add/ ).

Next, run this command on your local machine, replacing {PORT} with the port # assigned to your Nitrous.IO box, and also changing `usw1` with the proper region found in the SSH URI of your boxes page ( https://www.nitrous.io/app#/boxes ).

To Upload:

```
scp -P{PORT} -r path/to/yourFolder action@usw1.actionbox.io:~/workspace
```

To Download:

```
scp -P{PORT} -r action@usw1.actionbox.io:~/workspace path/to/yourLocalFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also compress entire project to one zip file

```
zip -9 -r all.zip workspace
```

and then download the zip file